# Dot net publish - Unable to Connect when trying to restore nugets

Tags: .net-core

I tried to publish .net core app for win 64 using this command.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64
```

I got this error.

```
Restoring packages for 
C:\projects\xxx\xxxStandard\Tests\UnitTestsCore\UnitTests.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to 
load the service index for source https://ap
i.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\projects\xxx\xxxStandard\xxxStandard.sln]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   A 
connection attempt failed because the connected pa
rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed
to respond [C:\projects\xxx\xxxStandard\xxxStandard.sln]
```

This restoring just failed in some particular projects, not all of them.
I tried to check if nuget cli alone is working and it is working. Also I tried to do this publish in and outside our company network.

Any ide how can I make this working ?

Egid

Comment: Check your network connection? Can you open `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` in a browser?

Comment: yes, I can see json in my browser